# TypeError: Cannot read object of type 'list'

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup, traceback

as far as i can tell, i haven't created a list, yet it's giving me a

> TypeError: Cannot read object of type 'list'.

Any thoughts?

Python newbie, so go easy.

Any and all help is appreciated.

sample url:

```
https://nclbgc.org/search/licenseDetails?licenseNumber=80479
```

here is the full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ncscribble.py", line 26, in <module>
    df = pd.read_html(url)[0].dropna(how='all')
  File "C:\Users\rkrouse\Desktop\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 987, in read_html
    displayed_only=displayed_only)
  File "C:\Users\rkrouse\Desktop\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 815, in _parse
    raise_with_traceback(retained)
  File "C:\Users\rkrouse\Desktop\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\compat\__init__.py", line 404, in raise_with_traceback
    raise exc.with_traceback(traceback)
TypeError: Cannot read object of type 'list'
```

Full Code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from urllib.request import urlopen
import time
import csv
import pandas as pd
import os
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email import encoders

def license_exists(soup):
    with open('NC_urls.csv','r') as csvf:
        urls = csv.reader(csvf)
        for url in urls:
            if soup(class_='btn btn-primary"'):
                return False
            else:
                return True


with open('NC_urls.csv','r') as csvf: # Open file in read mode
    urls = csv.reader(csvf)
    for url in urls:
        df = pd.read_html(url)[0].dropna(how='all')
        df = df.groupby(0)[1].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x.dropna())).to_frame().rename_axis(None).T
        if not license_exists(soup(page, 'html.parser')):
            # if the license is present we don't want to parse any more urls.

            break


df.to_csv('NC_Licenses_Daily.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `df = pd.read_html(url[0]).dropna(how='all')`? Anyway, add a `print(url)` as 1st statement in `for url in urls:` and check the output.

Comment: tried that and it gave me a AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'dropna'.  So, it's still referring back to a list.

Comment: Then it's `df = pd.read_html(url[0])[0].dropna(how='all')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you encounter a type error, it is usually a good idea to print the value, like this:

```
    for url in urls:
        print(repr(url))
        df = pd.read_html(url)[0].dropna(how='all')
```

It will give you:

```
['https://nclbgc.org/search/licenseDetails?licenseNumber=80479']
```

This is because a CSV *row* is itself a list.  You need to obtain the first list element and pass that to the HTML processor:

```
    for url in urls:
        df = pd.read_html(url[0])[0].dropna(how='all')
```

To get the page data, you could use `requests`:

```
import requests
page = requests.get(url[0]).content
```

Comment: got ya.  So, now it's telling me page is not defined, which i understand why, i'm just sure not how to correct it.

Comment: What do you expect for `page`?

Comment: It was part of script I was using from other project.  Ended up on this one somehow.

Comment: I apologize, I still need to have html.parser correct? Or can I just scrap it?

Comment: I think in this case, you shouldn't use `pd.read_html` with an URL, but download the URL separately and feed the result of that to both pandas and BeatifulSoup.

Comment: got ya.  the problem i run into is coming to SO for help and i get an answer that puts like 3 or 4 lines of code into one line and just take it at face value, not truly understanding how it works, then i run into problems further in my script that i have no idea how to solve.  I appreciate your suggestion and will figure out how to do it.  thanks for your help.